# Input type with decimal seperator and dot

Tags: android, android-inputtype

I was wondering how can i get keyboard like in the picture below on 10 inch tablet with decimal seperator and dot? I need to do it programmatically via setInputType().

[image]

Comment: Did you even tried to search this first?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but none of the solutions worked for me

Comment: Then you should post what have you tried??

Answer (score -1):

```
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Try following in your activity

```
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

It will show numeric keypad with separator and dot when edit text got focus.